# how to get value from json file cannot read the property of 'number' error

Tags: node.js, json, discord.js

Here is my json file after using

```
let data = await fs.readFileSync ("./data/json/serversettings.json","utf8", function(err) {
        if (err) throw err; 
    })
console.log(data)
```

i get response

```
    {
  "guilds": {
    "627832600865800222": {
      "guildautorole": "default",
      "welcomeChannelID": "000",
      "logchannel": "default",
      "guildMemberCount": 7,
      "guildOwnerID": "348832732647784460",
      "voicelogchannel": "default",
      "guildOwner": "Ethical Hacker",
      "prefix": ",",
      "guildID": "627832600865800222",
      "guildName": "Bot testing server"
    },
    "637301291068030997": {
      "prefix": ".",
      "guildID": "637301291068030997",
      "guildName": "test server 3",
      "guildautorole": "default",
      "welcomeChannelID": "default",
      "logchannel": "default",
      "guildMemberCount": 4,
      "guildOwnerID": "348832732647784460",
      "voicelogchannel": "default",
      "guildOwner": "Ethical Hacker"
    },
    "GUqGqFanJuN7cRJx4S2w": {}
  }
}
```

who can  i get the value of `welcomeChannelID` from `627832600865800222` to variable called `ID`

well my 2nd time so my be wrong

```
console.log(data['guilds'][gdata.guild.id])
```

i get error Cannot read property '627832600865800222' of undefined

what can i do to make it pass as string or how can i get `"welcomeChannelID": "000",` or `000` in `console.log`

i think it may look like this

```
console.log(data['guilds'][gdata.guild.id][welcomeChannelID])  //error in [gdata.guild.id] box
```

output :

```
000
```

Comment: try  data = JSON.parse(data)  then try to get the id 
console.log(data['guilds'][gdata.guild.id])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data` type is `string` so  you need to parse it before trying to access it as an object.

```
let data = await fs.readFileSync ("./data/json/serversettings.json","utf8", function(err) {
        if (err) throw err; 
    });
data = JSON.parse(data);
let ID = data['guilds'][gdata.guild.id]['welcomeChannelID'];
console.log(ID);
```